# Variable not updating inside of button pressed action

Tags: ios, swift, variables, button

I am currently having trouble with variables inside of my popup view. I am using an @IBAction button press to execute the code when the button is pressed. I have then set it up to a variable called buttonPressedTag and have printed it out every time I reopen the view it always stays at 0.

Code:

```
var buttonPressedTag: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
    buttonPressedTag = 1
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(buttonPressedTag)
}
```

Comment: When you dismiss the view, the buttonPressedTag variable, and its incremented value, are lost. You'll need to keep track of that value somewhere else.

Comment: How would you suggest I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it, I had to make the buttonPressedTag variable global throughout the whole project as in it looked like this.

```
var buttonPressedTag: Int = 0

class ViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
    buttonPressedTag = 1
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(buttonPressedTag)
}
}
```

Can someone please explain why this worked?

Comment: This is actually because once the view is dismissed, all the variables inside of it are killed and reset. Just like any normal UIViewController. Then since you go back onto it and the variable is set to 0, that is what is printed.

Comment: How many views need to know about the button you're pressing? If it's just one, you might be best off keeping your counter in the view controller leading into the view controller with buttons on it and implementing a delegate protocol. Here's a post: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/. A protocol is a specified way of doing things. A delegate is something in charge of doing something. So you'd make your parent VC in charge of updating the counter and keeping the `buttonPressedTag` in the parent view.

Comment: That makes more since, Thank You!